# why do I get a connection failure with MQTT in android studio app

Tags: android, android-studio, mqtt

I have an app which uses MQTT app to connect to io.adafruit.  When I am on a regular wifi it connects fine but when I am at our place in rural Montana we use a satellite internet and most of the time I get a connection failed or connection disconnected error in my log.  Is this because of the lag between the satellite and our place? And is there anyway to account for this so the connection has time to connect and stay connected?

I haven't posted any code because I don't see anything that seems to give the connection a specific time to connect.

I know the code works and connects because as I said in town over a fast internet it works fine.

I will try to post code if someone asks for something specific.

Thanks

OK here is my manifest code:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mqttkotlinsample">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MQTTkotlinsample"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

    >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MQTTkotlinsample.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Build Gradle(module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mqttkotlinsample"
        minSdkVersion 33
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.4'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
}
```

Here is the code for the connection etc.:

```
package com.example.mqttkotlinsample

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.schedule
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.PendingIntent.*
import android.os.Build

class ClientFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mqttClient : MQTTClient

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "LAUNCHED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //val webView = findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView

        activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {

            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {


                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

                if (mqttClient.isConnected()) {

                    Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "CALLBACK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

                    //Toast.makeText(context, "MQTT connection success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // Disconnect from MQTT Broker
                    mqttClient.disconnect(object : IMqttActionListener {
                        override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {

                            Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Disconnected")

                            //Toast.makeText(context, "MQTT Disconnection success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                            // Disconnection success, come back to Connect Fragment
                            //findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_ClientFragment_to_ConnectFragment)
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {

                            //Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Failed to disconnect")
                        }
                    })
                } else {

                    //Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Impossible to disconnect, no server connected")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?


    ): View? {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client, container, false)


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

        val on =0
        var open = "50"
        var switch = 1
        var switch2 = 1
        val webView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView
        webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxx")
        // Get arguments passed by ConnectFragment
        val serverURI   = arguments?.getString(MQTT_SERVER_URI_KEY)
        val clientId    = arguments?.getString(MQTT_CLIENT_ID_KEY)
        val username    = arguments?.getString(MQTT_USERNAME_KEY)
        val pwd         = arguments?.getString(MQTT_PWD_KEY)

        // Check if passed arguments are valid
       if (

           serverURI   != null    &&
            clientId    != null    &&
            username    != null    &&
            pwd         != null        ) {

           Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "TRYING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
            // Open MQTT Broker communication
           mqttClient = MQTTClient(context, serverURI, clientId)

           Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "FLAG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
               // val updatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,updatedIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
           PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

           Log.d("serverURI",serverURI)
           Log.d("clientID",clientId)
           Log.d("username",username)
           Log.d("pwd",pwd)
            // Connect and login to MQTT Broker
           mqttClient.connect( username,
                pwd,

                object : IMqttActionListener {

                    //this is where we need intent
                    override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {


                        Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "SUCCESS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

                        val message = on.toString()


                        val feeds = "/feeds/"
                        val video = "video"
                        //val get = "/get";
                        val topictripb   = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(video).toString()
                        if (mqttClient.isConnected()) {
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                            Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "CONNECTED!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                            mqttClient.publish(topictripb,
                                message,
                                1,
                                true,
                                object : IMqttActionListener {


                                    override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {



                                    }

                                    override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {

                                        Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Failed to publish message to topic")
                                    }
                                })


                        } else {

                            Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Impossible to publish, no server connected")
                        }
 }

                    override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                        Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Connection failure: ${exception.toString()}")

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "MQTT Connection fails: ${exception.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        // Come back to Connect Fragment
                        //findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_ClientFragment_to_ConnectFragment)
                    }


                },

                object : MqttCallback {


                    override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                       val feeds = "/feeds/"
                        val wifi = "wifi-connection"
                        val video = "video"
                        val temp ="temperature"
                        val lev = "level"
                        //val lev2 = "level2"
                        val trip = "trip"
                        val date = "date"
                        val bat = "battery"
                        //val get = "/get"
                        val topict  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(temp).toString()
                        val topicb  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(bat).toString()
                        val topl  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(lev).toString()
                        //val topicll  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(lev2).toString()
                        val topictr  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(trip).toString()
                        val topicd  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(date).toString()
                        val topicv  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(video).toString()
                        val topicr  = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(wifi).toString()
                        val msgt = message.toString()
                       if (topic == topict) {

                           PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

                            val newh = Integer.valueOf(msgt)

                            val imagea = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView5)
                            val newHeight = newh*4
                            val newWidth =100
                            imagea.requestLayout()
                            imagea.layoutParams.height = newHeight
                            imagea.layoutParams.width = newWidth
                            if (msgt <= "70"){
                                imagea.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("FFF7F9FA"))
                            }
                            else if ("70" < msgt && msgt < "90"){
                                imagea.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3BDCF1"))
                            }
                            else if (msgt > "90"){
                                imagea.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EC3156"))
                            }
                           Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "TEMP WAS READ??????????????????")

                        }
}

                    override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable?) {
                        Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Connection lost ${cause.toString()}")
                    }

                    override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken?) {

                        Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Delivery complete")
                    }
                })
 feeds = "/feeds/"
            val temp = "temperature"
            val get = "/get"
            val topictemp   = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(temp).toString()
            Timer().schedule(2000) {

                if (mqttClient.isConnected()) {

                    mqttClient.subscribe(topictemp,
                        1,
                        object : IMqttActionListener {

                            override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {

                                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE


                                //val msg = "Subscribed to: $topictemp"
                                val messagec = 0.toString()
                                val topictempget   = StringBuilder().append("").append(username).append(feeds).append(temp).append(get).toString()
                                mqttClient.publish(topictempget,
                                    messagec,
                                    1,
                                    true,
                                    object : IMqttActionListener {
                                        override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                                        }

                                        override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                                            Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Failed to publish message to topic")
                                        }
                                    })


                            }

                            override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                                //Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Failed to subscribe: $topictemp")
                            }
                        })
                } else {
                    //Log.d(this.javaClass.name, "Impossible to subscribe, no server connected")
                }}
}
```

and lastly this is the log:

```
2022-10-01 09:19:06.907 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 193247900; UID 10157; state: ENABLED
2022-10-01 09:19:06.917 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-10-01 09:19:06.918 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400006e897ef210, tid 1672
2022-10-01 09:19:06.921 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-10-01 09:19:06.923 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-10-01 09:19:06.923 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2022-10-01 09:19:06.924 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb400006e897ef690: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2022-10-01 09:19:06.925 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb400006e897ef690: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x70a412b080) (first time)
2022-10-01 09:19:06.936 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-10-01 09:19:06.936 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-10-01 09:19:06.937 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400006e897ee310, tid 1672
2022-10-01 09:19:06.937 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2022-10-01 09:19:06.937 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x1e3ff8000 size 0x8000
2022-10-01 09:19:06.938 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/Gralloc4: allocator 4.x is not supported
2022-10-01 09:19:06.941 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-10-01 09:19:06.945 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-10-01 09:19:06.945 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400006e897ed4d0, tid 1626
2022-10-01 09:19:06.947 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2022-10-01 09:19:06.949 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb400006e897ee550: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2022-10-01 09:19:06.949 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb400006e897ee550: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x70a412b100) (first time)
2022-10-01 09:19:07.020 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
2022-10-01 09:19:07.840 1626-1745/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(166) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2022-10-01 09:19:08.515 1626-1672/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=155.88ms min=1.56ms max=1351.77ms count=9
2022-10-01 09:19:08.848 1626-1752/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/AlarmPingSender: Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttService
2022-10-01 09:19:08.849 1626-1755/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(171) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2022-10-01 09:19:09.863 1626-1756/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/AlarmPingSender: Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttService
2022-10-01 09:19:09.874 1626-1626/com.example.mqttkotlinsample D/com.example.mqttkotlinsample.ClientFragment$onViewCreated$1: Connection failure: Connection lost (32109) - java.io.IOException: Connection is lost.
2022-10-01 09:19:35.331 1626-1653/com.example.mqttkotlinsample W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

I did not write the log as code as there was to much code then sorry.  I also only included the log after the ServerURI the client the username and pwd were logged.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the code that connects mqtt would be interesting, or at least information about the mqtt client you use so someone may know how to configure it's timeouts. It's possible that bad internet is just too bad though and no stable connection would be possible. Not just lag, dropped packets especially.

Comment: Post the code and the actual error log.

Comment: It would be useful to see the MQTT broker log as well, but I would look to set the keepAlive value for the connection, try setting it to something like 90 seconds to start with

Comment: I have tries various ways to set keep alive (default is 60 sec.) but have not found one that works with eclipse.paho.MQTT  All I can set on connect is username, password.  I am connecting to io.adafruit.  Where do I find the broker log?  I set the keep alive in my iOS mac mobile app but can't find it in the library for this.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the emulator since my iOS app on my iPhone works fine with a keep alive time of 30 seconds

Comment: This had to do with the service library not being updated.  I got this to work by going to github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android and clicking on issues as was suggested. They haven't updated the latest version but there was a solution. Somewhat involved but I finally got it going. Good luck.